# How can I print markdown with formatting _and_ all of its characters (including URLs of hyperlinks)?

Tags: printing, markdown

I want to be able to print (onto paper) markdown that looks like this when formatted:

[image: markdown screenshot]

```
# Demo
## subheader
Here is a [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com) link. 

_sample italics_

**Bold example**
```

When I print using https://stackedit.io/app or https://www.zettlr.com, it beautifies the document but removes / hides some of the content.

Without me needing to change *anything* in my markdown document, I want to be able to print it out such that ALL characters are preserved *and* it's beautified (i.e. shows headers in larger font, etc).

Also, for code blocks that contain long lines, I want the printed version to word-wrap it instead of showing horizontal scrollbars.

How can I do this?

P.S. Here is a feature request: https://github.com/Zettlr/Zettlr/issues/4630

Comment: So, you want to parser to *read* all the formatting characters and *change something* in order to get this beautiful output - and at the same time, you want the parser to *ignore* the formatting characters *not* replacing them? I don't think this will work, not without coding a special markdown parser handling things totally different than intended.

Comment: @xph See the screenshot above. I just want to be able to print the entire doc in the way that the program already displays on the screen in editing mode. I like how _all_ characters are visible, even though there is also formatting. Thanks.

Comment: I unserstand and see the output you want to have - but that's like asking for a browser that would display the HTML tags as well as interpreting them. This is no out-of-the-box feature, this is not the intended use case and i guess you'll have to code a parser for this special need to get this done.

Comment: @xph I think these apps have already done the hard part, which you're calling "like asking for a browser that would display the HTML tags as well as interpreting them". Now that that's done, I just want to print what's already visible. I don't see how printing to paper would take any more work than what the app already did to "print" it to the screen as it already does in the screenshot above.

Comment: What you see there is an *instruction* for the *markdown formatting*. It's not *content*. This instructions have a distinct defined function. You want them to behave in a way they are not created for. I don't know how to make that any more clear.

Comment: Am I wrong to assume that a black and white laser printer can print _anything_ that a screen can show in black and white? That's all I'm asking for. I did not fudge the screenshot above. StackEdit does a wonderful job of interpreting the formatting instructions in a way that leaves them visible in the editor _even while_ it also increases font size, adds italics and bolding, etc. So then it's frustrating that those formatting characters disappear during printing. There should be an option to preserve them, especially because otherwise URLs in links are lost on the (paper) printed copy. @xph